# UI application in Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a UI application built using Angular , Bootstrap and HTML5 which interacts with number of backend services. In order to deploy this application in PCF , should this be converted to a Spring Boot app? Or is there a way to use any of available buildpacks to deploy this UI app in PCF?

Comment: I think you can use this [BuildPack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack) to serve static files i.e. your AngularJs HTML files.

Comment: Check available build packs using `cf buildpacks` and if `staticfile_buildpack` is listed, you are good to go. Otherwise use a -b flag in your push command as - cf push -b staticfile_buildpack <yourapp>

Comment: Thanks a lot Sanjay and Ring Bearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there is no need to deploy backend services, I would go with the cloudfoundry static buildpack.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html

Otherwise you will need to decide how you are going to deploy the backend services for this application. There are a number of buildpacks available that could be used for deploying the backend services and delivering the frontend content within the same app (one of them being, as you mentioned the java buildpack that can be used to deploy a spring boot app). Here is a list of available buildpacks:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/

Answer (score 1):

Its not needed to convert your application to spring boot, but doing so will definitely make life easier for you, trust me. Once u convert ur app to a spring boot right, you can remote debug ur application by jst running ur app as a spring boot app.